# Creating subdomain with nginx server block returns Server Not Found

Tags: linux, nginx, subdomain

this is a problem I don't get to solve.

I have a VPS on DigitalOcean, installed manually a LEMP stack on it and I have the domain with hover.com

Everything seems to work if you visit my server [site](http://erzei.net). But I'm trying to configure two things that just simply don't work.

First, I'm trying to configure a new subdomain (blog.erzei.net) but when I try to access the address in the browser(any) it returns a Not Found. Even if I try

```
 curl -I blog.erzei.net
```

it returns a Could Not Resolve Host, although erzei.net works fine. I don't know if it has something to do with the domain registar or it's a nginx configuration problem. As far as the Hover support told me, any redirects I configure from the registar won't work because I'm using the DNS's of DigitalOcean. So, I think I must configure every new subdomain from my nginx configuration.

The code of the server block is the following, which is located after the main block in the default config file of sites-available:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name blog.erzei.net;

    root /example/directory.net;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

The main block for the server is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /main/directory.net

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name erzei.net www.erzei.net;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The second issue is that www to non-www redirect also doesn't work. Maybe is related with my first problem. If I type www.erzei.net I get a Server Not Found response in the browser. The configuration is, again, inside my default config file of nginx.

```
server {
    server_name www.erzei.net;
    return 301 $scheme://erzei.net$request_uri;
}
```

I'vre researched a lot from the official nginx docs, the wiki, the DigitalOcean forum and here. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the DNS A record for the subdomain? Every DNS name must have a corresponding A / CNAME record that maps the DNS name to either an IP address or another DNS name.

Comment: Both the redirect and the blog subdomain are working, I suggest you mark the question answered. You should have the blog in a subdirectory for SEO value, if you care about that, as a subdomain it's treated as a completely different website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment of the question, I needed to edit some DNS records on DigitalOcean, not in the registar administration.

Seems that I missed this link during my research, hope it helps other folks.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-test-dns-subdomains-with-digitalocean-s-dns-panel